# How to restrict access to content on a website?

Tags: php, file-permissions

Lets say I have a domain: www.example.com, and I upload all the necessary files trough ftp.
There are 10 pages on the site I want to be public, all the other content shouldn't be accessible to a visitor. As it is now, anyone could type in the following "www.example.com/data/text.txt", and get all the information in it.

So is there a way to restrict access to content on a site this way?

Comment: Find out which Webserver you (or your hoster) is running (most probably Apache). Then look into their documentation (Apache: .htaccess can enforce BasicAuth)

Comment: or just add a htaccess file with `Order deny,allow Deny from all` (apache < 2.4) and `Require all denied` (apache >= 2.4)

Comment: They use Apache, and they gave me access to an ftp server only, do I have to contact them?

Comment: just create a file .htaccess in the folder you want protect

Comment: You can achive this goal adding a IP filter in you Cpanel

Comment: You can restrict access to files and folders via FTP client by right clicking on a file or folder and click file permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the version of the apache server:

create a `.htaccess` file in the folder you want to protect with the following content for apache version below 2.4 [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html):

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

and for apache versions >= 2.4 [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html)

```
Require all denied
```

For custom error pages add the additional lines:

```
ErrorDocument 404     /404.html #for error 404 file not found
ErrorDocument 401     /404.html #for error 401 unauthorized
ErrorDocument 403     /404.html #for error 403 forbidden
```

If you want you can also use `mod_rewrite` as follows:

Add the following content to your `.htaccess` file in the root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^yoursite1.html - [L]
RewriteRule ^yoursite2.html - [L]
RewriteRule ^error.html - [L]

#everything else
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ error.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: it works! Is there a way to redirect with this file to 404.php?

Comment: have a look at my updated answer, if mod_rewrite is enabled you can rewrite everything you don't want to a custom site. (I'll update my answer again for another option)